# how to create com objects using python

Tags: python, com

In Visual studio there is an option to register as an Interop COM. I want to achieve the same using python language. If someone can help me how to go about this. I did my research but couldnt find anything.

Comment: Did you find http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/com_overview.html

Comment: Although it seems like not a good SO question, but people seeking the answer to this question will definitely being brought to this page. An up vote from me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import win32com.server.register
   win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(ClassName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like my namesake comments above. Use the [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) module. Alternatively you can use the [comtypes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/comtypes/) module instead. Because python is a interpreted language you can use COM in 2 separate ways. By generating a interoperability layer or by dynamic typing. Both *comtypes* and *pywin32*, can do dynamic typing. Additionally pywin32's **win32com** module can also generate a interoperability layer, this has a drawback tough as dynamic typing is often easier to handle. Here is a simple example that generates a interop like compatibility layer (if on does not exist) in excel. Then the script opens a existing worksheet and edits the first cell value:

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch

xl = EnsureDispatch ("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'c:\temp\test.xlsx')
sht = wb.Worksheets(1)
sht.Cells(1,1).Value = "yeah this works"
```

**PS:** Stack overflow already automatically suggests a lot of resources for you to follow in the related sidebar.